# How to define HSV renge for the Brown color in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, hsv

I defined HSV color values (for both low and high brown) to detect brown color in my code. However, I noticed that the range is not defined appropriately and the program detects other colors like black and orange as brown.

```
low_brown = np.array([5, 0, 0])
high_brown = np.array([17,255,255])
brown_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_brown, high_brown)
brown= cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=brown_mask)
```

How can I define the right HSV ranges for brown color?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a color picker tool like [this one](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm) to find good values for your low and high brown colors. Note that most color pickers use hue values from 0-360 and saturation/lightness from 0-100, so you will have to normalize the values to the scale used by cv2, as [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) documentation mentions.